# IE does not find JS code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsf, jspdf

I'm using JSF to call a JS function but it is not working in IE with compatibility mode, does anyone know why is this happening? It works perfectly in chrome and Mozilla, but in IE doesn't find the function sendPdf().

JSF:

```
<af:commandButton text="#{bundle['enviar']}"
                onclick="sendPdf()"
                disabled="#{!page.notEmptyTable}" />
```

js:

```
<afh:script> function sendPdf(){
pdf();
document.getElementById("stringPdfDocument").value= doc.output();
document.getElementById("enviarDocumento").click(); } </afh:script>
```

pdf function uses the following include:

```
<afh:script source="/jsLibs/jspdf.js"/>
```

Comment: Tried IE in **non** compatibility mode

Comment: @Kukeltje Is working in that way, but my clients works with different versions of IE, that's why my partners asked me to do it in compatibility mode.